# How to change sjp.int y-axis label

Tags: r, label, yaxis, sjplot

How do you change the y-axis label using sjp.int?  I see axis.title for changing the x-axis but nothing for changing the y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plot_model()`, which returns a ggplot-object, and then modify the axis labels.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- plot_model(model, type = "int")
p + labs(y = "my title")
```